# Resharper quick-fix puts this qualifier in front of properties and not just private fields

Tags: c#, resharper-7.0

I am using VS 2012 and Resharper 7. In my project the convention to access private fields is always with "this" qualifier, just to make it clear it's private (e.g. this.myPrivateField). Properties should not be accessed with the this qualifier. We configured resharper and that's working fine.
But if I use a quick-fix option, it always puts the this qualifier in front of the used property (e.g. this.MyPublicProperty). Is there any way/setting to turn of that behaviour?

Comment: I think you are better off to write to the developers directly. We had in the past a couple of these little issues aswell and they were always very helpful and thankfull for these comments.

Comment: Your standard is bizarre. `this.` doesn't imply a member is private. It only implies that it's an instance member. That may be why ReSharper has no setting to distinguish between one kind of instance member and another.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but this standard is set by the customer and I just want resharper not to prefix the properties with the this qualifier. Thx for the advice anyway. I will try and contact the developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the feature to work "For fields in this class", or "For fields", if you're sure to also follow the very standard convention of making all fields private.

Turning on "For fields in this class" allows me to have this code after an automatic cleanup:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string myPrivateField;

    public string MyPublicProperty { get; set; }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        this.myPrivateField = "Cucumber";
        MyPublicProperty = "Cucumber as well";
    }
}
```